# Virtuemart does not send Mail

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

i have got something strange, i installed Joomla, and all mail functions work in contact form...
but in virtuemart after ordering something NO Mail is sent,..not to the person who orders and not to the owner,...
any suggestiions?

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to change the mail settings to SMTP in Global Configuration, although if you're standard contact forms are working then it could be something else such as a misconfiguration in your Virtuemart settings, or even your email account blocking the emails as spam.

I would definitely recommend to set your mail settings to SMTP though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain how VM handles mail, but going on the assumption that it's using the core Joomla mailer, you might have a look at your mail setup. My own experience with the default **PHP Mail Function** is that it works great as long as you're sending mail to a single recipient. If  you Google the subject, you'll find lots of articles that suggest the default Joomla PHP Mail Function won't mail to multiple recipients. Why this is, I don't know, as PHP Mail clearly has the ability to do so.

In any case, I've always found the simple solution is to use SMTP with password authentication (create a dedicated email address specifically for the purpose of doing mailings). You can easily setup the SMTP within Joomla by going to **Global Configuration** | **Server** | **Mail Settings**.

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart handle mail send procedure due to order status. Please check the selected values to:

> configuration -> checkout -> Default Order Status to send email to shopper
>
> configuration -> checkout -> Default Order Status to send email to vendor